# nidaqmx: prevent task from closing after being altered in function

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I am trying to write an API that takes advantage of the python wrapper for NI-DAQmx, and need to have a global list of tasks that can be edited across the module.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1) Created an importable dictionary of tasks which is updated whenever a call is made to ni-daqmx. The function endpoint processes data from an HTTPS request, I promise it's not just a pointless wrapper around the ni-daqmx library itself.

e.g., on startup, the following is created:

```
#./daq/__init.py__
import nidaqmx
# ... other stuff ...#
TASKS = {}
```

then, the user can create a task by calling this endpoint

```
#./daq/task/task.py
from daq import TASKS

# ... 

def api_create_task_endpoint(task_id):
    try:
        task = nidaqmx.Task(new_task_name=task_id)
        TASKS[task_id] = task
    except Exception:
        # handle it
```

Everything up to here works as it should. I can get the task list, and the task stays open. I also tried explicitly calling `task.control(nidaqmx.constants.TaskMode.TASK_RESERVE)`, but the following code gives me the same issue no matter what.

When I try to add channels to the task, it closes at the end of the function call no matter how I set the state.

```
#./daq/task/channels.py
from daq import TASKS

def api_add_channel_task_endpoint(task_id, channel_type, function):
    # channel_type corresponds to ni-daqmx channel modules (e.g. ai_channels).
    # function corresponds to callable functions (e.g. add_ai_voltage_chan)
    # do some preliminary checks (e.g. task exists, channel type valid)
    channels = get_chans_from_json_post()
    with TASKS[task_id] as task:
        getattr(getattr(task, channel_type), function)(channels)
        # e.g. task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
```

This is apparently closing the task. When I call `api_create_task_endpoint(task_id)` again, I receive the `DaqResourceWarning` that the task has been closed, and no longer exists.

I similarly tried setting the TaskMode using `task.control` here, to no avail.

I would like to be able to make edits to the task by storing it in the module-wide `TASKS` dict, but cannot keep the Task open long enough to do so.

2) I also tried implementing this using the NI-MAX save feature. The issue with this is that tasks cannot be saved unless they already contain channels, which I don't necessarily want to do immediately after creating the task.

I attempted to work around this by adding to the `api_create_task_endpoint()` some default behavior which just adds a random channel that is removed on the first channel added by the user.
Problem is, I can't find any documentation for a way to remove channels from a task after adding them without a GUI (this is running on CENTOS, so GUI is a non-starter).

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't use the Python bindings for NI-DAQmx, but

`with TASKS[task_id] as task:`

looks like it would stop and clear the task immediately after updating it because the program flow leaves the `with` block and [Task.__exit__()](https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/blob/master/nidaqmx/task.py#L115) executes.

Because you expect these tasks to live while the Python module is in use, my recommendation is to *only* use `task.control()` when you need to change a task's state.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't remembered to check the .__exit__() method.